# Space between currency sign and amount

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

I need to add space between currency sign and amount for all currencies in `nuxtjs/i18n`.
For now I've something like this:

`$1,739.10`

and I need:

`$ 1,739.10`.

nuxt.config.js:

```
numberFormats: {
  'en-US': {
    currency: {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'USD',
      currencyDisplay: 'symbol',
      useGrouping: true,
      symbol: '$',
    },
  },
}
```

and I'm using it as:

```
$i18n.n(173910, 'currency')
```

Any ideas how to handle it?

#edit

done with `<i18n-n>`

Comment: Please share the relevant code

Comment: It is meant to not have any space I guess. If you still want some, you will need to do it yourself with a split and join.

Comment: Just format the number as `decimal` instead and manually print the currency symbol. It looks like you have it already somewhere after all.

Comment: Alternatively you can use the `<i18n-n>` tag and use scoped slots to customise everything. https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/essentials/number.html#custom-formatting

Comment: What happens if you would set the symbol with space? `symbol: '$ '`

Comment: Quite a simple hack but could work well.